# Models of computability agreeing on decidable sets.

Tags: logic, computability

By `model of computability' I mean a precise characterization of which functions one counts as partially computable. So, for example, I say that Turing machines are a model of computability and Register machines are another model of computability. My question is the following. Suppose that we have two models of computability $A$ and $B$. Suppose that we know that the $A$-decidable sets are exactly the $B$-decidable sets. Can we conclude that the $A$-partially-computable functions are exactly the $B$-partially-computable functions?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Just wanted to mention there are also the [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and [theoretical computer science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) SEs to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Is it acceptable to post the same answer in different stackexchange sites?

Comment: For reasonable models of computability, a (total) function $f$ is computable iff the set of codes of pairs $(n,f(n))$ is decidable, so the answer to your question is yes. But if you allow unreasonable models, then no: I could define a model by declaring "decidable" to have its usual meaning while "computable" means "computable in the usual sense but taking only finitely many distinct values."

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I think I misstated my question. Some computable function may be partial. In that case the graph may not be decidable. So I want to ask whether A-partially-computable functions are exactly the B-partially-computable functions. Sorry for not being clear since the beginning.

Comment: Your question requires a definition of the notion of "model of computability". Without that the notions of "A/B- partial computability" and "A/B-decidability" have no meaning.